# merge multiple Date rows into single and count Standard SQL

Tags: sql

I'm working on multiple rows with the same Date and don't know how to combine and count for the amount customers.

The raw Data

[image: The raw data]

Here is my expected result

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "group by" like:

```
select [Date], count(customer_id)
from tablename
group by [Date]
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks Eray!

Comment: @NamDoan The square brackets not "standard SQL" however

Comment: well that's fine by the way

Comment: @NamDoan glad to help, i appreciate if u select the answer as "correct answer" by clicking the tick sign on the left